# When is $(-1)^m2^{l-2m}{2\,m\choose m}$ an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please let me know for which values of $l$ is $(-1)^m2^{l-2m}{2\,m\choose m}$  an integer.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the binomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only obstacle to your number being an integer is its 2-adic valuation.  But
$$\nu_2((-1)^m 2^{l-2m} \binom{2m}{m}) = l - 2m + s_2(m)$$ where $s_2(m)$ is the number of ones in the binary expansion of $m$. Have a look at http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2028!

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and for the link.  Then the integrality condition is $l - 2m + s_2(m) > 0$? Or it is necessary to add other condition for $s_2(m)$?

Comment: This answer is abacadabra for an elementary number ntheory student.

Comment: Geniuses you'll find on math overflow, not here. It was not my intention to insult or offense, i assumed you were in a ENT course because you tagged it as such

Comment: @JuanOspina: Close; you want $l - 2m + s_2(m) \ge 0$. For example, $\nu_2(1/2) = -1$.

Comment: @Unit, thank you very much, you are very kind.